# Erroneous output in C++ arithmetic

Tags: c++

I am trying to perform the following arithmetic in C++. While doing so C++ (gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.4-6ubuntu2) 4.6.4) is giving me the ouput as infinity. Although the output should be 0.1001. Can someone please explain the strange behaviour of C++ compiler

```
    unsigned man=10009999,exp1=8;
    double retrievedVal=(man)*pow(10,-((exp1)));
    cout<<"retrieved val="<<retrievedVal<<"\n";

Ouput: inf
```

Comment: This doesn't compile on my machine - you are trying to unary negate an unsigned integer, which gives me an error.

Comment: @dwcanillas If negating an unsigned integer doesn't compile, your compiler is broken.

Comment: Why are you using `unsigned int` anyways if you want a negative number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you negate an unsigned integer, you will not get what you expect. This is easily verified by the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  unsigned a = 8;
  double b = -((a));
  std::cout << b;
}
```

Output:

```
4.29497e+009
```

To fix it, change exp1 to a regular `int`, or use a cast(not recommended, you should really prefer to just change the type).

### Why doesn't it work

On an unsigned type, all values that would represent negative numbers in signed types, actually represent a(usually very large) positive number.

In a 2's complement machine with a 32-bit integer, `8` would be represented as `0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1000`. `-8` would actually be represented by `1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1000`. But you're dealing with an unsigned, which will treat this same representation as a positive number. The same binary data now represents `4294967288`. 10 to the power of this value most certainly will overflow a double, which is why you're getting `inf`.

Answer (score 2):

Don't negate an unsigned value. A dirty fix would be to cast to your output variable type . .

```
double retrievedVal=man*pow(10,-(double)exp1);
```